# How to fix file not found on Heroku?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I have a laravel project deployed in Heroku, in my Laravel project i have a php script i made to receive json, my `php` script is in public folder, when i use `php artisan serve` to serve the project, the script is accessible with no problem through the following `url`:

```
http://localhost:8000/receive-alert/api/historique/create.php
```

My problem is when i deploy my Laravel project the `url` isn't accessible anymore:

```
https://gestioncapteursincendie.herokuapp.com/receive-alert/api/historique/create.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the folder in which my php script (`receive-alert`) was a repository of its own which is why heroku for some reason didn't recognize it, it works fine now.